# Ransack sort by model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have model Program, which has a method 'rating' that returns rating of the program(Program has many reviews, each review has value from 1 to 5, this method returns its average). I need to use Ransack to create sort_link based on this 'rating' method and I have no idea how. Someone has any ideas?

Comment: So in your view are you calling that method for each program when you loop through them?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Im looking to do something similar.

Comment: @Scott yes I am calling that method for each Program

Comment: @Deekor no, I haven't looked into that since I wrote this question, sorry